# Everything temporarily becomes nil when anything happens

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

In my `viewDidLoad()` I call this:

```
NSString *testString = @"https://test.com/?code=12345";
NSDictionary *testParams = [self parseRequest:testString];
```

Just to see if the `parseRequest` method works. The method is called just fine:

[image]

But when I go one step further (i.e. any of the code in the method executes) everything becomes `nil` and I can't process the `urlString`:

[image]

After the method finishes executing, everything seems to go back to normal (except none of the code in the `parseRequest()` method has worked)

I've tried the following things, none of which have worked:

- Move the method contents to `viewDidLoad()` (everything still becomes `nil` when I act on the `urlString`)
- Using a URL instead of an `NSString`

EDIT: I stripped the entire class down as small as I could. Here's the final result:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *failureLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *loadingBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *testString = @"https://test.com/?code=12345";
    NSString *testParams = [self parseRequest:testString];
}

- (NSString *) parseRequest:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSLog(@"???");
    return @"";
}

@end
```

It almost certainly has to do with `UIWebView`...right? (I create the webView in interface builder, but even if I do nothing with it I still get this issue)

Comment: Did you only call `parseRequest` on `viewDidLoad`? Is it a problem if `parseRequest` return a `NSString` and `testParams` is a `NSDictionary`?

Comment: post full code of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @trungduc That's just the result of half an hour of me shooting into the dark trying to figure out what was breaking. Has no bearing on the issue

Comment: @PhilipS Did you only call `parseRequest` on `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @PPL I commented out all other code in viewDidLoad() and still have this issue. Another thing to note is that after this code executes, "self" is no longer nil but "testString" and "testParams" are.

Comment: @trungduc Yeah, that's the only thing I called. I'll post the entire class in a sec

Comment: @Philip S i tested your code working perfect try to clean derived and close xcode than after try

Comment: agree with @JigarDarji if still have a problem, delete the entire ViewController and create another one

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, clean the project, quit xcode and restart it

Comment: I cleaned the project, deleted derived data, reinstalled the app, and restarted Xcode. Same issue still. It's not even the call to parseRequest() that's the error; after anything is executed after initializing "testString", "testString" just becomes nil.

Comment: Moved the code to a new file (just straight copy and pasted it) and it works now. Oh well. Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: With a very high probability this is either an Xcode bug or feature. Try to just _NSLog_ the `urlString` before the return statement, and also _NSLog_ the `testString` after the call to `parseRequest`. I bet you see the stings all intact.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Yeah, I'm betting there were 2 problems: one with the original code I had (not the snippets provided here) and one with Xcode, and I misinterpreted the Xcode issue to be my code's issue.

Answer (score 0):

The values are already there, the debugger might not be showing the value of the variables because

1. The optimization level for your current configuration is not set to `None` while debugging.[image]
2. You are debugging using Release configuration where optimization by default is the highest(Fastest, Smallest) as shown in above image.

[image]

Just `NSLog` the variable `urlString` and it should print the value even if `LLDB` shows it as nil.